# Combine two videos in python and get frame-precision duration of the end of the first clip within the new combined clip

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to combine two videos (mov files) in Python and get the frame-precision duration of the end of the first clip within the new, combined clip so that I can skip to the end of the first clip/start of the second clip within the newly combined clip.

Here is how I combine the two videos.

```
def concatenate_videos(video1_path, video2_path, output_path):
    input1 = ffmpeg.input(video1_path)
    input2 = ffmpeg.input(video2_path)

    vid = '/Users/johnlawlor/projects/yesand/backend/media/videos/vid.mp4'
    aud = '/Users/johnlawlor/projects/yesand/backend/media/videos/aud.mp3'
    ffmpeg.concat(input1, input2, n=2, v=1, a=0).output(vid).run()
    ffmpeg.concat(input1, input2, n=2, v=0, a=1).output(aud).run()

    input1 = ffmpeg.input(vid)
    input2 = ffmpeg.input(aud)
    ffmpeg.concat(input1, input2, n=2, v=1, a=1).output(output_path).run()
```

Then I get the duration of the first clip.

```
def _get_duration(local_file_path):
    new_addition_metadata = ffmpeg.probe(local_file_path)
    duration = float(new_addition_metadata['streams'][0]['duration'])
    return duration
```

However, when I skip to the time that is returned by this logic, it skips to a few frames before the actual start of the second clip, so I get a jerky effect that seems like a bug.

I am currently using ffmpeg-python. I am open to any other Python libraries.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (add link video files that reproduce the issue, or create sample video files using FFmpeg CLI). Does the issue related to the audio, or is it reproducible with video only? Please post an executable code (include the import statements).

Comment: @johnklawlor You need to find out the FPS and also the number of video frames in `input1` (don't count the audio frames). The calculation is `expected_Time = ( total_vid_frames / FPS )`...